# how do I change regexp_substr(to_char(bar), '^.*?$', 1, 1, 'm') to only read 132 characters each time

Tags: oracle

how do I change the query below so it only reads and displays 132 characters each line

```
with w(id, line#, line, rest) as (
  select id, 1, regexp_substr(to_char(bar), '^.*?$', 1, 1, 'm'), 
         substr(to_char(bar), regexp_instr(bar, '$', 1, 1, 1, 'm')+1)
  from foo
  union all
  select id, line#+1, regexp_substr(rest, '^.*?$', 1, 1, 'm'), 
         substr(rest, regexp_instr(rest, '$', 1, 1, 1, 'm')+1)
  from w
  where rest is not null ) cycle id, line# set is_cycle to '1' default '0'
select id, line#, line from w order by id, line#;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
with w(id, line#, line, rest) as (
  select id, 1, SUBSTR(regexp_substr(to_char(bar), '^.*?$', 1, 1, 'm'), 1, 132), 
         substr(to_char(bar), LEAST(132, regexp_instr(bar, '$', 1, 1, 1, 'm'))+1)
  from foo
  union all
  select id, line#+1, SUBSTR(regexp_substr(rest, '^.*?$', 1, 1, 'm'), 1, 132),
         substr(rest, LEAST(132, regexp_instr(rest, '$', 1, 1, 1, 'm')+1))
  from w
  where rest is not null ) cycle id, line# set is_cycle to '1' default '0'
select id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY line#) AS line#, line
from w
where TRIM(line) <> ''
order by id, line#;
```

What it does is:

- line: truncate (`SUBSTR(..., 1, 132)`) the first full line to the first 132 characters (which does nothing for lines shorter than 132)
- rest: grab the rest of the CLOB of either the first full line, or whatever comes after 132 characters, whichever starts first (`substr(rest, LEAST(132, ...))`)

---

### Response to the sequence question in comments:

To create a sequence over a partition, your best bet is self-join with a grouped-and-sorted:

```
SELECT t.MO_ID, g.DOC_NO, ...
FROM <your table> t
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ROWNUM AS DOC_NO, MO_ID
  FROM <your table>
  WHERE <same as in outer query>
  ORDER BY MO_ID
  ) g ON (g.MO_ID = t.MO_ID)
WHERE ...
```

or with a CTE + ROW_NUMBER() window function:

```
WITH
  t AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM <your table>
    WHERE ...
    ),
  g AS (
    SELECT MO_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MO_ID) AS DOC_NO
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MO_ID FROM t) x
    )
SELECT t.MO_ID, g.DOC_NO, ...
FROM t
JOIN g ON (g.MO_ID = t.MO_ID)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64582/discussion-on-answer-by-ziggy-crueltyfree-zeitgeister-how-do-i-change-regexp-sub).